# Why is my image empty when sending it through my app to my server, but not when sending it through Postman?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I made a component for uploading an image from the gallery to an endpoint on my server.

Endpoint:
Method: POST

Path: /api/profile/images

Input data: Form-data (multipart)  {"image":  (Image to be added)}

Response: JSON
Status codes:
201 (Image added successfully)
400 (User can have a maximum of 5 images)
500 (Server error)

Now when i send an image through postman everything works, but when i send it with the app, the image is empty.

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    const { granted } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
  
    if (!granted) {
      alert("Brak pozwolenia do bilbioteki!");
      return;
    }
  
    const pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
    if (pickerResult.canceled) {
      return;
    }
  
    const uri = pickerResult.assets[0].uri;
    const filename = pickerResult.assets[0].fileName!;
    const type = pickerResult.assets[0].type || `image`;
  
    const formData = new FormData();
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
  
    const imageFile = new File([blob], filename, { type: type });
    console.log(imageFile); //{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "84ef0d3e-db44-44e4-a864-3f194a0c0602", "lastModified": undefined, "name": "IMG_1898.png", "offset": 0, "size": 575124, "type": "image"}}
    formData.append('image', imageFile, filename);
    console.log(formData); //{"_parts": [["image", [File]]]}
    try {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'https://xxx.xxx:3005/api/profile/images');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwtToken}`);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
      xhr.send(formData);
  
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 201) {
            alert('Pomyślnie dodano zdjęcie');
          } else if (xhr.status === 400) {
            alert('Użytkownik może mieć maksymalnie 5 zdjęć');
          } else if (xhr.status === 500) {
            alert('Błąd serwera');
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

On backend i log the headers and got this, 'content-length': '246'. Earlier when logging the blob object it showed "size": 575124.

I tried with fetch and axios already.

Comment: Got it working with base64

Comment: Hi, please do not put answers in comments.  Write a regular answer